# How do I configure webfarm for a simple asp.net demo application

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, session-state, web-farm

I am just making a demo application and want to configure asp.net to use webfarm. How can I do so?

I have already configured my session mode to use SQL Server and it works perfectly. What should I do next? I am using Windows 7, SQL Server 2008 and Asp.Net 4.0 webforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need multiple machines - set up the application on both of them and configure both web sites to have a common host name/header. You also need to setup a common machine key for encrypting view-state etc. In real web farm setup, you will have a s/w or h/w load balancer that will be route requests to either server based on load. In case, you don't have a load balancer then use your local hosts file to resolve the common host name - for example, for first couple of request, use machine 1 and then switch it to machine 2 for next few and so on.